# Hide Volume OSD in Windows

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, window

I want to hide this OSD (preferably only the second bigger part of it containing controls for chrome.exe).

Is it possible to do so without installing any additional software using Windows Registry or something?

I am also interested in knowing if it's possible to change its position to perhaps bottom-right corner. Is it possible to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. chrome://flags
2. Media Session Service -> Disabled
3. Restart Chrome

Comment: This is a good workaround for chrome. What about other applications? I wish there was a way to this system wide using Registry as OP wanted.

Comment: @Shayan I remember there is a program which completely removes it (even the volume slider). Maybe that will suit you.

Answer (score 2):

CHROME (Apr 2021)

`chrome://flags` -> `Hardware Media Key Handling` -> `disabled`

FIREFOX

`about:config` -> `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled` -> `false`