# Can I disable Windows 10's media preview on volume change?

Tags: window, media

When I change volume using the keyboard I get the volume slide (which is nice), but on it's right there's a preview with controls. Half the time this is unrelated to what I'm doing (e.g. I'm on VLC but get a preview to a random Firefox tab). Can I disable the media title and controls next to the volume slider?

[image: media control]

Comment: This is a similar question but for Chrome only: [Hide Volume OSD in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1433451/1838)

Comment: Have you got Windows Power Toys Fancy Zones enable?  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/windows-10-powertoys-how-to-use-and-configure-fancyzones/

Comment: @John - no, I didn't like that feature. How would that help here?

Comment: Remove or disable Fancy Zones.

Comment: I see this in two computers, Zones is disabled in one and the second doesn't have Power Toys installed.

Comment: I believe this is up to the software reporting the information. In Spotify for example, you can disable this.