# System Volume OSD shows unwanted meta data & controls

Tags: windows-10, audio, osd

I recently noticed that my system volume OSD has become polluted with meta data and a control interface that I do not want to have. This extra data seems to be present when a tab in a web browser contains a video.

[image]

There used to be [some workarounds](https://superuser.com/a/1445751/598567) for this with Chrome, however that linked workaround doesn't seem to work anymore,

While this issue is happening with various web browsers, is also seems to be happening with Discord as well. **I would really prefer a  system wide solution** rather than playing Whac-A-Mole with various app settings to get this resolved.

What can I do to restore my Windows volume OSD to only contain the slider that displays the system output volume?

Running Windows10 Pro Build 19045

Comment: Edge just renamed the flag slightly to enable-media-session-service

Comment: Try to disable `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling`. The option for `chrome://flags/#enable-media-session-service` seems to have disappeared (but disable it if it still exists).

Comment: Its happening with more than just web browsers though. This seems to be happening with Discord as well, so I would rather a system wide solution rather than playing Whac-A-Mole with various app settings.